# input field is not getting displayed by using ContractForm

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, drizzle

```
<DrizzleProvider options={drizzleOptions}>
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Welcome Doctor</h1>
                        <h2>Enter your public address:</h2>
                        <ContractForm contract="Records" method="loginDoctor" labels ={['Enter your public address']}/>
                        {/* <AccountData accountIndex ={0} units={"ether"} precision={2}/> */}
                    </div>
                </LoadingContainer>

            </DrizzleProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass the drizzle instance and drizzleState to ContractForm